# What is the difference between vxworks 653 and vxworks 7

Tags: vxworks

I am new to vxworks. And I hope to start a project with vxworks based on ARM A53 architecture. It seems vxworks 653 and Vxworks 7 both support the CPU. But it is hard to tell which one is better from the name. Is vxworks 653 similar to vxworks 7? What is the major difference?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a vendor support question and not a programming question. Contact the software vendor for information about the differences between versions of their product. Most companies publish either a feature matrix or a *What's new* when a new version is released.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VxWorks 653 implements the ARINC653 interface, which VxWorks 7 does not. "653" is not a version number, but refers to that specific feature. Unless you specifically need the ARINC 653 interface, VxWorks 7 is probably what you need. Their new "Helix" platform reportedly merges 653 and 7.

Answer (score 0):

VxWorks 653 implements the ARINC653 for things that fly and need to be certified by the FAA. VxWorks 653 comes with only limited functionality needed for certified systems. The assumption is you are going to keep your code base to a minimum because every line needs to be certified.

VxWorks 7 is very feature rich in comparison, with all kinds of optional network protocols, middleware, security features and drivers. More like working with an eLinux that something like FreeRTOS.